# Blender Eevee render not working properly

Tags: rendering, cgi, render, blender, direct3d

So I am new to Blender (v 2.91) and I was trying out these render options i.e Eevee and Cycle. The Cycle (only CPU) option works fine for me but in the Eevee option, the cube/object appears black or sometimes disappears (As shown in the screenshot below).

I am not sure why this is happening. I tried googling it but didn't get a proper resolution. I am attaching some screenshots for reference also with my current preferences in Blender.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN5Lj.jpg)
This is Cycle render with CPU option (works fine)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtiAV.jpg)
This is Cycle render with GPU option (does not work fine)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqUN7.jpg)
This is Eevee render (does not work fine)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knPXC.jpg)
System Preferences

Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

I had just the same problem today. I also use 2.91 and my objects were not visible in Materials preview and Eevee render.
But I found the right switch:
Render Properties (on the menu on the right) --> Performance --> turn on High Quality Normals.

That worked for me, I hope it also works for you.